# column title too long

Tags: tables

I've been helped with this issue before, but i'm having trouble extrapolating from the code I already have. Basically I want the fourth column title to look just like the others. Have a look:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,siunitx,booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,siunitx,booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\sisetup{group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=no}


\usepackage{%booktabs, 
            makecell, %tabularx
            }
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\author{}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table*}[!htb]
\caption{Estimates of pay-performance sensitivity.}
\label{tab:table1}
OLS regressions of CEO salary and CEO total compensation on change in shareholder wealth. Standard errors in parentheses.

   \medskip
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}L lll@{}}
    \toprule
\thead[l]{Dependent\\ variable}
            &  \thead[l]{CEO\\
                         salary\\
                         (eq. \ref{eqn:first})}


                                            & \thead[l]{CEO total\\
                                            compensation\\
                                            (eq. \ref{eqn:second})}

& CEO salary \\ (not controlling for industry) \\


    \midrule

\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Assuming that `CEO salary` and `(not controlling for industry)` both belong to the same column, you can use `\thead[l]{CEO salary \\ (not controlling \\for industry)}` to obtain a result similar to the other columns. Please also check your preamble, as you load various packages twice and also define the same column type twice.

Comment: Thanks @leandriis , any idea about this?: Misplaced \noalign.
\midrule ->\noalign 
                    {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global \@...
l.413 \end{tabularx}

Comment: Your example with my suggested modification should not yield such an error. Most likely you forgot the double backslash  before the `\midrule`.

Answer (score 2):

In the following MWE, I have used the `\thead` command provided by the `makecell` package in order to intruduce linebreaks in the column header of the fourth column analogously to the linebreaks in the other columns:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}


\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[!htb]
  \caption{Estimates of pay-performance sensitivity.}
  \label{tab:table1}
OLS regressions of CEO salary and CEO total compensation on change in shareholder wealth. Standard errors in parentheses.

 \medskip
 \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
 \small
 \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}L lll@{}}
      \toprule
      \thead[l]{Dependent\\ variable}
      &  \thead[l]{CEO\\  salary\\ (eq. \ref{eqn:first})}
      & \thead[l]{CEO total\\ compensation\\ (eq. \ref{eqn:second})}
      & \thead[l]{CEO salary \\ (not controlling \\ for industry)} \\
      \midrule
   \end{tabularx}
  \end{table*}
\end{document}
```